# How do I debug an obfuscated executable?

Tags: reflector

I have an obfuscated executable and I want to debug the EXE. I've tried to look into the source code with the .NET Reflector. While looking into the source, an internal exception has been thrown within the .NET Reflector. So I want to get the source code or to debug the application. Are there any possibilities to debug the app or to get the source in C# syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Reflector doesn't give you *the* source code. It gives you a reverse engineered version of what the source code might have looked like based on the actual IL. If the code has been obfuscated identifiers will make little sense, but you can still view the code using Reflector. You can dump the generated C# code from Reflector using the [FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) add-in.

Comment: The FileDisassembler doesn't help. The exception also occurs.

Comment: @System.Data: Hmm that sounds strange. I have looked at obfuscated assemblies without problems like that. Is it just one specific assembly that crashes Reflector or is it all of them? You could try to run ILDasm instead, but that will only give you IL and not C# code. However, IL is fairly readable IMO.